# What is the best way to start the conversion (Orthodox) process?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

Should I call a synagogue and make an appointment with the Rabbi and explain that I am interested in converting? Should I call multiple synagogues?

Are there classes for people who are interested in converting? Can you start prior to being able to be shomer shabbat (I live to far from the closest Sephardic Synagogue but would like to eventually relocate so I am able to do so.) I would like to get a feel for the community before relocating.

Should I mention that I know Hebrew and I have Jewish ancestry (paternal grandfather)? Does it matter?

How will I know if my conversion will be accepted by the Rabbinate in Israel?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Phil!

Comment: Note that in general this site is intended for general questions, not specific questions about an individual's own circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Phil!  We have another question that covers this topic so -- while the individual situations aren't identical -- I've marked it as a duplicate.  How to know if a conversion will be accepted in Israel is a separate question from how to get started, so please ask that separately if we don't already have it.  Thanks, and I look forward to seeing you around the site!  And best wishes in your Jewish journey.

Comment: Hi Phil, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! [This](http://crazyjewishconvert.blogspot.com/) blog is a great resource for those seriously considering conversion.

Comment: I would suggest looking at [Conversion to Judaism](http://www.rabbis.org/conversion.cfm) of the Rabbinical Council of America as they have already addressed the issue, including acceptance by Israel. They can give you the names of rabbi(s) in your area who work with gerim and can help you on your journey. 305 Seventh Avenue, 12th Floor
New York, New York 10001
Phone 1: 212-807-9000
Phone 2: 212-741-7522
Fax: 212-727-8452
To contact the Rabbinical Council of America by email office@rabbis.org